# NFS shared file system that uses all PCs hard drive

Tags: linux, filesystems, cluster, shared-folders

I'm building a small cluster with desktop computers that run on Debian 11.

I want a shared /home directory where all user's files are located. I know that the ideal way to do this is to have a master node that has a lot of storage capacity where the directory is hosted and have the rest of the computers be NFS clients.

The problem I have is that all the PCs have the same hard drive storage. I want to have the /home directory mounted on all the hard drives at the same time to take advantage of the hardware I already have.

So, my questions are, Is it possible? If yes, is it a good idea? What happens if one machine goes offline? What application allows me to do this? If not, what alternative do I have?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you plan to use the same username on different machines? If yes, you should not use a shared /home directory. Instead you could make it a git repository and specify in the .gitignore which config files you want to share. Plus: it comes with all the advantages

Comment: @mashuptwice thanks for your comment. But what if I want to do some distributed computing? Not having a shared file system could be unpractical. Also, the current version of the cluster has like 4 Tb of memory in storage, I don't think that's viable with a repo. Although I do that for my main PC, that's great.